# JSON value++, cant change value

Tags: jquery, json

I create JSON database, 1st question display correctly becouse val = 0, when i change val for val=1, i get 2nd question. So everything working, but when i was trying to use button... ye nothing...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="question.json"></script>
    <title>Quiz</title>

    <script>
$(function() {

$.getJSON("question.json", function(json) {
    val = 0;
    if($("#next").data('clicked')){
        val = val+1;
    }
    var x = json.Endokrynologia[val];
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = x.title;
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = x.id;
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = x.question;
    document.getElementById("ans1").innerHTML = x.answear01;
    document.getElementById("ans2").innerHTML = x.answear02;
    document.getElementById("ans3").innerHTML = x.answear03;
    document.getElementById("ans4").innerHTML = x.answear04;
    document.getElementById("ans5").innerHTML = x.answear05;
    document.getElementsByName("answear")[0].value = x.answear01;
    document.getElementsByName("answear")[1].value = x.answear02;
    document.getElementsByName("answear")[2].value = x.answear03;
    document.getElementsByName("answear")[3].value = x.answear04;
    document.getElementsByName("answear")[4].value = x.answear05;


});

 $("input[name=answear]:radio").change(function () {
        return ans = $("input[name=answear]:checked").val();
   });
$("#result").click(function(){
                     alert(ans);
                     });


});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="demo">
    <h1 id="title"></h1>
    <p id="id"></p><p id="question"></p>
    <input type="radio" name="answear"><label id="ans1"></label></br>
    <input type="radio" name="answear"><label id="ans2"></label></br>
    <input type="radio" name="answear"><label id="ans3"></label></br>
    <input type="radio" name="answear"><label id="ans4"></label></br>
    <input type="radio" name="answear"><label id="ans5"></label></br>
</div>
<button id="result">button </button>
<button id="next">next</button>
</body>
</html>
```

also try:

```
$("#next").click(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
```

becofe getJSON

```
and $("#next").click(function(i, val) {
var val =0 ;
var val*1+1;
   $.getJSON("question.json", function(json) {....}
});
```

That's working when clicking button but, when load file i have no output...I missing something but what?

Comment: Show the html please.  The `return` statement inside your success handler does nothing, since this function does not return to your code.

Comment: done, all hmtl added

Comment: @zze I think you're assuming that word is supposed to be the english word "answer".  What is the correct spelling of "Endokrynologia" do you think?  XD

Comment: ups. xD ye copy and paste with 1st mistake made. :D ty : - )

Comment: yes... i change that already... but nothing change :D

Comment: yes currently is HTML one. the 1st one. xD

Comment: What is `var val*1+1;` supposed to be? Please post code that can be run at least. See [mcve].

Comment: Verify that your logic for setting the values on the `document.getElementsByName("answer")` is actually setting the values to something.

Comment: i just put 2 options i already tray, main working code for output you have in main html, 1st code. where val = val + 1;

Comment: honestly no... answer is actually setting no value... but answear did work  :D co i change all for answear for easy copy :D

Comment: Yes, the comment about the spelling wasn't helpful - it's just a name, it has no semantic value.  You could have used any ID and it would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `next` button isn't really doing anything.  You want it to manipulate some value and then populate the form accordingly.  Something more like what's shown below.  Note that I've removed the call to `getJSON` for clarity, since all it should be doing is to set the value of `json`:

```js
var json;
var val;

function populate(x) {
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Data: "+x;
  // population of other stuff here, removed for clarity
}

$(function() {
  val = 0;
  //   code to populate the json variable from the external resource is not used, it's being replaced with a stub
  // $.getJSON("question.json", function(response) {
  //     json = response;
  //     populate(json.Endokrynologia[val]);
  // }
  //
  // ----- <stub> -----
  json = { Endokrynologia: [ "one", "two", "bar", "foo" ] };
  populate(json.Endokrynologia[val]);
  // ----- </stub> -----

  $("#next").on('click', function(event) {
      val = val + 1;
      populate(json.Endokrynologia[val]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <h3 id="title"></h3>
    <p id="id"></p>
    <p id="question"></p>
    <input type="radio" name="answear"><label id="ans1"></label></br>
    <input type="radio" name="answear"><label id="ans2"></label></br>
    <!-- other elements removed for clarity -->
    </div>
    <button id="result">button </button>
    <button id="next">next</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: cool but i need to call.. for clarity :D my database have 10 000 position :D if i will create JSON inside main file... it will be unreadable... there is maybe other way?!

Comment: i have around 20 topics: 1 of them is ENDOKRYNOLOGIA,

Comment: That's a different question all together :)  But you still should only need the one global namespace to hold your data.  Sounds like you need to do a more refined getJSON call to get only the category you are currently working.  Good luck, I have to go

Comment: good job. everything is working:D i was to tied to read your code correctly.. needed more time :D